# preg_match with name being last in input

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to get the value from a input field, but the name value is last.

```
<input value="joe" type="hidden" name="firstname">

preg_match('/input value="(.*?)" type="hidden" name="firstname"/', $request, $firstname);
```

This is what I am doing, but it's not working.. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your `<input …>` identified, you can use the following pattern to extract all attributes (taking care of the value delimiters (single quote, double quote, space)).

```
<?php

$input = '<input value="joe" type="hidden" name="firstname">';
$attributes = array();
$pattern = "/\s+(?<name>[a-z0-9-]+)=(((?<quotes>['\"])(?<value>.*?)\k<quotes>)|(?<value2>[^'\" ]+))/i";
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  $attributes[$match['name']] = $match['value'] ?: $match['value2'];
}
var_dump($input, $attributes);
```

will result in

```
$attributes = array(
    'value' => 'joe',
    'type' => 'hidden',
    'name' => 'firstname',
)
```

https://gist.github.com/1289335

Answer (score 0):

Try that regex

```
input(.*)?(name=\"(\w+)\")(.*)?
```

and get the 3rd result

Answer (score 0):

your regex is is fine
the last arg of preg_match returns an array

element 0 = entirematch

element 1 = first parenthesis match

```
$request = '<input value="joe" type="hidden" name="firstname">';

if (preg_match('/input value="(.*?)" type="hidden" name="firstname"/', $request, $matches)) {
    echo "MATCHED: ", $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `<input>` parameters appear in this order in the *source*. Note that they appear in arbitrary order if you look at them with firebug for example.

Consider replacing hardcoded space '' chars with '`\s+`' to improve robustness.